# Принудительное падение сборки (jenkins + pytest)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, jenkins, pytest

Знаю, что подобные вопросы уже были ранее. У меня вопрос чуть развернутее :)

Значит, что имеем:
Python + Selenium + Pytest + Jenkins

Моя задача:
Реализовать механизм проверки сервера на доступность, перед запуском тестов. Ибо надоело, когда при недоступности сервака, все тесты начинают фейлится градом :) Хочется реализовать эту проверку, чтобы перед тестами все уже было проверенно. И ко всему прочему, чтобы сборка в Jenkins падала при недоступности сервака. Очень хотелось бы сделать все на стороне кода, а не Jenkins, чтобы проект было легко переносить.

Работает все так:
Jenkins запускает собирает и запускает код. Перед тестами запускаются фикстуры, потом идут сами тесты.

Моя реализация фикстуры(запускается перед тестами):

```
import pytest
import logging
import allure
import config
import requests

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def f2_check_connection_to_server():
    """ Фикстура для проверки доступа к серверу.
    Если фикстура обнаружила, что сервер недоступен, тесты не запускаются.
    """
    logging.info('Проверка доступности сайта')
    with allure.step('Проверяю доступность сайта'):
        url = f'{config.MAIN_URL}api/check_email/qweqwe@123q132.ru'
        logging.info('Производится запрос на сервер')
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
        if not response.status_code:
            logging.critical(f'Сервер недоступен. Тесты остановлены.\nURL: {url}')
            pytest.exit(f'Сервер недоступен. Тесты остановлены.\nURL: {url}')
        logging.info('Ответ получен. Сайт доступен.')
```

Вот моя реализация. В принципе она меня устраивает. Этот вариант был написан за 5 минут на коленке(часть кода вырезана).

Проблема:
Суть проблемы в том, что при запуске тестов в Jenkins, если эта проверка не прошла, Jenkins не фейлит сборку и с виду все хорошо. А это неудобно, и ручные тестеры не понимают что происходит... Вроде написано успешно, а вроде тесты по отчетам не проходили. Объяснять как смотреть лог бесполезно :)

Вот как получается по логу(обратите внимание, в конце SUCCESS):

```
 _pytest.outcomes.Exit: Сервер недоступен. Тесты остановлены.
URL: http://*****/api/check_email/qweqwe@123q132.ru 
no tests ran in 8.37 seconds
Exit: Сервер недоступен. Тесты остановлены.
URL: http://*****/api/check_email/qweqwe@123q132.ru
Report successfully generated to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/*****/allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Какие у меня варианты:
1. Создавать переменную окружения в коде о результате тестов, чтобы потом ее проверял Jenkins(неплохое решение).
2. Использовать плагин для Jenkins, который будет искать в логе текст "Сервер недоступен. Тесты остановлены." и валить сборку(решение среднее ибо плагин не умеет фейлить сборку, а только делает ее нестабильной).
3. Вместо pytest.exit использовать pytest.fail(решение среднее ибо тогда падение присваивается самому первому тесту, хотя он даже не отработал).

Вот как-то так. Хотелось бы услышать какие есть еще варианты, в головах умных людей :)

Comment: Вариант использовать хук https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/_modules/_pytest/hookspec.html#pytest_sessionstart 
Он выполняется когда сессия уже создалась, но даже не начали собираться тесты в кучу.

Или в фикстуре явно эксешн кинуть например? 

"Падение присваивается первому тесту" потому, что объект f2_check_connection_to_server передаётся всё таки тесту, и от скоупа зависит только, как будут создаваться инстансы (раз на сессию, модуль, тест)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположим, в jenkins job определяются переменные: 
$SCHEME$HOST:$PORT, описывающие адрес тестового стенда.

**Вариант 1**:
В существующую фикстуру f2_check_connection_to_server добавить:
в случае успешного коннекта с тестовым стендом создавать переменную окружения, например:
`os.environ['URL_CHECKED'] = 1`

Чтобы фейлить job, нужно добавить в него ещё один шаг с типом 'Execute shell':

```
if [[ -z "${URL_CHECK}" ]] ; then
echo "Check connect to $SCHEME$HOST:$PORT - FAILED"
exit 1
else
echo "Check connect to $SCHEME$HOST:$PORT - SUCCESS"
unset URL_CHECK
exit 0
fi
```

**Вариант 2**:
 Доверить проверку коннекта джобе, добавить первый шаг с типом 'Execute shell':

```
echo "Проверка доступности стенда $SCHEME$HOST:$PORT"
curl -I -s -S $SCHEME$HOST:$PORT
```

При невозможности установить соединение шаг джобы фейлится, и джоба также фейлится.

**Вариант 3**: (Питоноводческий):
 Так же доверить проверку коннекта джобе, добавить первый шаг с типом 'Python script':

```
import urllib2
import os

url = os.environ['SCHEME'] + os.environ['HOST'] + ':' + os.environ['PORT']
print '************* Check network availability for stand:', url, ' *************'

request = urllib2.Request(url)
try: 
    urllib2.urlopen(request)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e
```

Результат аналогичен п.2: При невозможности установить соединение шаг джобы фейлится, и джоба также фейлится.

**Примечание**:
Если нужно часть кода выполнить, а часть нет в зависимости от какого-то условия, то в jenkins есть шаг с типом Conditional step (singe)  (и Conditional steps (multiple)).
С ними можно покопаться и настроить ветвление логики в джобе.

Answer (score 0):

А почему не используете `returncode`? `pytest.exit` может ведь закончить тестовую сессию с любым кодом:

```
pytest.exit('Сервер недоступен', returncode=1)
```

ЕМНИП, Jenkins останавливает выполнение пайплайна с первым ненулевым exit code'ом (если явно не указать обратное, к примеру `pytest || true`), так что чуть подправьте вызов `pytest.exit` в фикстуре и готово.